# big file is not downloading completelly

Tags: php, apache

I have server with [these](http://prntscr.com/egmxc0) configuration.
You can see the configuration and i have code to download file is here.

```
    set_time_limit(0);
    $nfile="/home3/knight/public_html/abc/test.mp4";
    header("Pragma: public"); // required
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers 
    header( "Content-Type: " . self::get_download_content_type( $file_path ) );
    // change, added quotes to allow spaces in filenames, by Rajkumar Singh
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($nfile)."\";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    //header("Content-Length: ".filesize($nfile));
    readfile("$nfile");
    exit();
```

issue is after some mb browser shows download is completed but when i open that video, then its not completed. not getting what is the issue here.

Comment: Why did you disable the Content-length header?

Comment: @syck you think this will cause issue?

Comment: Depends on your client. But I see no ''post_max_size'' directive in your config. Usually this limit is set to 2M. Also try to upload different files with different sizes, to find out where the cap applies.